# Galaxy behind the Ring Nebula

Tags: galaxy, observational-astronomy, messier-catalog, ngc

Would anyone be able to reference the galaxy in the background of this image of the Ring Nebula:

[image]

It's obviously not a Messier object, I'm more confident in it being in the New General Catalogue.

Comment: It's IC 1296, see [this photograph](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap091106.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andy pointed out, the spiral galaxy is IC 1296. You're correct that it's not in the Messier Catalog, but it's obviously in the revised Index Catalogue. [NED](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/nph-objsearch?objname=IC%201296&extend=no&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA+or+Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES) and [SIMBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%402868623&Name=IC+1296&submit=display+all+measurements) have some more information on it:

- **Morphological type:** SBbc, as classified according to the [Hubble sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_sequence). It's a spiral galaxy with two clearly visible arms.
- **Redshift:** 0.017075 $\pm$ 0.000070, according to [Marzke et al. (1996)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?1996AJ....112.1803M).
- **Distance:** 66.6 Mpc to 68.9 Mpc after corrections, depending on your distance definition of choice ([angular diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter_distance), [luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_distance), etc.). Large uncertainties arise when calculating the difference from redshift. For comparison, [Andromeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) is approximately 0.78 Mpc away, and the [Ring Nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_Nebula) is $10^{-3}$ times *that* distance.
- **Apparent magnitude:** 14.80 $\pm$ 0.30, at visible wavelengths. For comparison, the Ring Nebula's apparent magnitude is 8.8.